# I want to compute a specific percentage in every text field and compute for the total grade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<tr>
    <td>Knowledge</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Knowledge" style="height: 30px; width: 220px;" class="computethis" id="knowledge" Placeholder = "Enter Grade"  autocomplete ="off" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Understanding</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="understanding" style="height: 30px; width: 220px;" class="computethis" id="understanding" Placeholder = "Enter Grade"  autocomplete ="off"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Process or Skills</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="process" style="height: 30px; width: 220px;" class="computethis" id="process" Placeholder = "Enter Grade"  autocomplete ="off"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Performance or Products</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="performance" style="height: 30px; width: 220px;" class="computethis" id="products"  Placeholder = "Enter Grade"  autocomplete ="off" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Grade Total </td>
    <td><input type="textbox" name="grade" style="height: 30px; width: 220px;" id="totalgrade" Placeholder = "Average Total"  autocomplete ="off"  readonly="readonly"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
</tr>   
<tr>        
    <td colspan='2'><button class="btn btn-info" style="40px" id="save_button" Onclick="insert();"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"> Save Grade</i></button><span class="alert alert-success" id="loading"></span></td>
</tr>
```

I just only had every text box get 25% each;

```
<script>
    // computation of average
    jQuery(".computethis").keyup(function(){
        var sum = 0;
        var avg = 0;
        jQuery('.computethis').each(function() {
            sum += Number(jQuery(this).val());
        });

        var $allx = jQuery(':text.computethis');
        var $emptyx = $allx.filter('[value=""]');
        var num = $allx.length - $emptyx.length ;
        if(num > 0) { avg = Number(sum/num); }
        //  jQuery('#prj_usgtot').val(sum);
        jQuery('#totalgrade').val(avg.toPrecision(2));
    });
</script>
```

How can I get every `textfield` a specific percentage, onkeyup it should automatically compute the average to get the total grade.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment yet, but why don't you also create an i that gets i++ as it goes through the each?
In your html, it should just be text. Textbox isn't a type.
Where is the issue?

Here, I have something working that you might like.
It also checks if there is only numbers

```
$(this).val().match(/^\d+$/)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4Buk5/

Comment: i had already a validation not allowing other char or special char in input text, here is my formula,hope it might clear out to you ,totalgrade = knowledge( value * .15) +understanding(value * .25)+Product(value * .25)+Process(value * .25) / 4 , by the way thanks for the ans, it also helps for my other problem and sorry for my english grammar